# Reading Specific Values From XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, file, weather-api

I have used a weather API to return temperature values in XML format and written them to a text file. My next step is reading the values in from the XML file for use in my program. This is the format the values are in;

```
<temperature value="21.37" min="18.89" max="22.78" unit="metric">
</temperature>
<humidity value="68" unit="%">
</humidity>
<pressure value="1019" unit="hPa">
</pressure>
```

I'd like to access the temperature value, but I am unsure how to do that by reading in from the text file especially considering that the text file is a lot longer than what I need. What would be the most efficient way to access the values I want?

EDIT:

```
<current>
  <city id="" name="">
    <coord lon="-0.45" lat="52.19">
    </coord>
    <country>GB</country>
    <sun rise="2016-08-16T04:48:13" set="2016-08-16T19:22:26">
    </sun>
  </city>
  <temperature value="22.06" min="19.44" max="23.89" unit="metric">
  </temperature>
  <humidity value="67" unit="%">
  </humidity>
  <pressure value="1019" unit="hPa">
  </pressure>
  <wind>
    <speed value="2.57" name="Light breeze">
    </speed>
    <gusts value="6.17">
    </gusts>
    <direction value="73" code="ENE" name="East-northeast">
    </direction>
  </wind>
  <clouds value="24" name="few clouds">
  </clouds>
  <visibility>
  </visibility>
  <precipitation mode="no">
  </precipitation>
  <weather number="801" value="few clouds" icon="02d">
  </weather>
  <lastupdate value="2016-08-16T10:44:02">
  </lastupdate>
</current>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml").Root
                      .Element(/*.... the rest of the hierarchy.. */)
                      .Element("temperature")
                      .Attribute("value").Value;
```

If you don't want to specify the entire way to the element you can:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml").Root
                      .Descendants("temperature")
                      .Select(element => element.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this method, `Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1`. I've updated my question with the full XML file.

Comment: @CBreeze - I've now executed both code sections on your given xml and it is fine. Are you sure that the xml in your output directory is the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectSingleNode` provided you loaded the XML with `XDocument`.

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/fb63z0tw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Usse xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("current").Select(x => new {
               temperature = x.Elements("temperature").Select(y => new {
                   value = (decimal)y.Attribute("value"),
                   min = (decimal)y.Attribute("min"),
                   max = (decimal)y.Attribute("max"),
                   unit = (string)y.Attribute("unit")
               }).FirstOrDefault(),
               humidity = x.Elements("humidity").Select(y => new
               {
                   value = (decimal)y.Attribute("value"),
                   unit = (string)y.Attribute("unit")
               }).FirstOrDefault(),
               pressure = x.Elements("pressure").Select(y => new
               {
                   value = (decimal)y.Attribute("value"),
                   unit = (string)y.Attribute("unit")
               }).FirstOrDefault()


            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = XElement.Parse("<root><temperature value=\"21.37\" min=\"18.89\" max=\"22.78\" unit=\"metric\"></temperature><humidity value=\"68\" unit=\"%\"></humidity><pressure value=\"1019\" unit=\"hPa\"></pressure></root>"); // this line is just to test. You can use what you are getting from API Call.

var result =   xml.Elements("temperature")
                            .Select(c => c.Attribute("value").Value); // the attribute value
```